# Elasticsearch deployment environment setup

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

We are working on setting up our elasticsearch backend for a production environment. Up until a few weeks ago, we were using Solr, but we decided to use Elasticsearch for a few reasons, but the biggest reason is for the distributed nature of the backend.

With that said, we've been looking for some documentation and best practices on deploying elasticsearch using amazon's services.

For the moment, we were considering using a extra-large box and then scaling out from there, but we aren't sure that is the best approach. For example, it may be better to have three mediums than one extra-large.

We intend to index around 100K to 150K documents per day up to around ten million docs.

The question is, can anyone provide a general environment / deployment diagram for elasticsearch or best practices in general?

Answer (score 0):

There's some docs for elasticsearch that talk about [EC2 deployment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/2011/08/22/elasticsearch-on-ec2.html).  There's an autodiscovery plugin based on EC2 tags or security groups or whatever you like.  You can also choose S3 for persistence, although that may not really be necessary.

I'd advise launching it in a VPC so you can have permanent internal IPs, in regular EC2 your internal IPs will change with every reboot even if you're using Elastic IPs.